# Uniqueidentifier issue with Casesensitive in SQLSERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, uniqueidentifier

```
UPDATE tableName SET COLUMN_NAME= '7a07c95d-015e-4897-81b7-55c41069095e' WHERE COLUMN_ID= '13GD454'
```

COLUMN_NAME is data type **uniqueidentifier**

It writing to SQL SERVER in lower case: '7a07c95d-015e-4897-81b7-55c41069095e'

But after retrieving data using JAVA JDBC, it is converting into upper case.

What is the reason behind this? Why does it convert to UPPER Case without explicitly performing a conversion?

Comment: `uniqueidentifier` is stored using an internal format.  When it is converted to a string, you get capital letters for hex digits (which I think is the standard way that hex values are usually rendered).

Comment: You are probably using `getString` to retrieve the value so the binary value is converted to a formatted string by the driver. I don't believe JDBC includes a `getUniqueidentifier` or `getGuid` method to return the native binary value, although you might be able to use `getBytes` and format the value as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the reason behind this?

GUID standard encoding is uppercase for the characters. It is not a string, it is a unique identifier, which is a GUID, so it returnes that and then formats it as string in the standard way.

This is dentical to:

Sore +01 in a number field, retrieve it - it has no leading + and no leading 0. It still accepts +01 as number, but it only stores the VALUE - and then returns the VALUE which gets formatted in a standard way.